# How to get (t) value for any arc length of a quadratic bézier curve

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

Is there any way to get the t value that correspond to specific arc length of a quadratic bézier curve.

there is a way to calculate the arc length for specific t value

[Calculate the length of a segment of a quadratic bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854907/calculate-the-length-of-a-segment-of-a-quadratic-bezier)

if there no way to get it,
How can I get points with equal fixed distance intervals
like this

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE55O.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Proper formatting is important; so please, consider to take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164).

Comment: You must invert the formula given in the linked answer, but that cannot be done in terms of elementary functions. You can do that via a numerical search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no closed-form formula, so you'll need to use numerical methods of some sort.

The simplest approach would be to just approximate the curve by a polyline. The relevant techniques are outlined in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321293/find-coordinates-of-equidistant-points-in-bezier-curve).