# Placing dots on quadratic Bézier curve at distance

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, analytic-geometry, quadratics, bezier-curve

I need to place points on a quadratic Bézier curve at length intervals `l`.

Found a pretty good resource at [quadratic Bézier curve length](https://malczak.info/blog/quadratic-bezier-curve-length) and used it to calculate the length of the entire curve. It covers the theory and the resulting formula is perfect for adoption into a piece of software.

However, doing the reverse - finding the coordinates or `t` from the path length is not a trivial task.

There is a great [Bézier curve primer](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing) covering, among several subjects, tracing of curves at equal distances, much like my case. I understood that there is no generic solution with radicals for Bézier curves. However, quadratic ones are just a subset...

Could there be a solution just for the quadratic case, or perhaps a good approximation? For instance, length of the curve, above, the formula was adopted to the point that there were no more integrals. Coders are left to write a function that has only a logarithm and a power of operations. No need for numeric methods.

Is it possible to come up with a formula/function, where instead of `t`, we pass `l` and the curve points, and get $$C(l) \quad l\in[0,L]$$ or a good approximation of it? I have only seen Newton solutions for this.

Comment: There are techniques and code in the answers here. They deal with cubic Bézier curves. Quadratics are simpler, of course, but I don’t see any way to take advantage of the simplicity. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321293/find-coordinates-of-equidistant-points-in-bezier-curve?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. Both lookup tables and Runge-Kutta and covered extensively in a few places. I am looking for an approximation to solve the problem "with radicals."

Comment: Highly unlikely that any simple closed-form formula exists. And formulas are over-rated, anyway. The polyline solution is fast is accurate enough for every application that I’m aware of.

Comment: If you want arclength formulae, use bi-arc curves or Pythagorean hodograph curves instead of general Bézier curves.